# I want to Convert word File to pdf using TCPDF & PhpWord

Tags: php

I want to convert my previous word/doc file to pdf but i was facing some error when i run this code **die** block is actually running but above it i will declare TCPDF and tcpdf values

```html
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$objWriter=\PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader('Word2007');
$phpword=$objWriter->load('edited.docx');

$rendererName=\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
$rendererLibrary='tcpdf';
$rendererLibraryPath=''.$rendererLibrary;
if(!\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRenderer(
    $rendererName,
    $rendererLibraryPath
)){
    die(
        "NOTICE:Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values".
        "<br>".
        "at the top of this Script as Appropriate for your Directory Structure"
    );
}
$rendererLibraryPath=''.$rendererLibrary;

$objWriter=\PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader($phpword,'PDF');
$objWriter->saveAs("test.pdf");
```

Comment: What error are you facing? `$rendererLibraryPath` should be full path to file. Check here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/2d2fe52b7aa4998e8449355771fb84c40a86f97e/src/PhpWord/Settings.php#L249

Comment: Can't able to convert doc file to pdf. when i run this file i got this message **NOTICE:Please set the TCPDF and tcpdf values
at the top of this Script as Appropriate for your Directory Structure**

Comment: as Justinas said, you are not setting the path into `$rendererLibraryPath`, you just set a string to he is not able to find the library